Prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a symplectic matrix, then $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is also an eigenvalue of such matrix
I´m trying to solve the following problem:

A symplectic $n\times n$ matrix $A$ follows this conditions:

$J$ is a $n\times n$ matrix
$J^2=-I$
$A^TJA=J$
$n$ is an even number

Prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a symplectic matrix $A$, then $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is also an eigenvalue of such matrix.

From previous items of the problem I´ve reached the following:

2 similar matrices have the same eigenvalues
$A^T$ is similar to $A^{-1}$ when $A$ is symplectic therefore
$A^T$ and $A^{-1}$ have the same eigenvalues

I still haven´t used the first condition ($J^2=-I$) so I think I might need to use it now. I´ve tried to start with the definition of an eigenvalue ($Av=\lambda v$) and try to end in something like $Aw=\frac{1}{\lambda}w$ where $w$ is a vector resulting from multiplying $A$, $J$, $A^T$, and $A^{-1}$ with $v$ but I don´t reach anything close. Also, I´ve reached that $|A|=\pm 1$ but I don´t think that contributes anything to the solution since that result is from a following item.
PD: Symplectic matrices isn´t a topic we have seen in class, so I don´t know if there are any other properties of this kind of matrices that can help

Hint: If $Av = \lambda v$ then $A^{-1}v = \frac{1}{\lambda}v$.

Show that $A^T$ and $A$ have the same eigenvalues, then use the above hint. If you need help, recall that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue iff $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$.

Some facts:

$(A+B)^T = A^T + B^T$.
$\det(A^T) = \det(A)$.
$\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$.
$J^{-1} = -J$.

Gluing these together,
$$ \det( A - \lambda I) = \det(J (A - \lambda I) (-J)) = \det(JA(-J) - \lambda I) = \det( (A^T)^{-1} - \lambda I) \\ =  \lambda^n \det(A^T)^{-1} \det( \lambda^{-1} I - A^T ) = (-\lambda)^n \det(A^T)^{-1}  \det( A - \lambda^{-1} I).$$
Now use that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue iff $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$.
